# Efeito Blur em imagem

Tags: android

Preciso fazer um efeito Blur em uma imagem de background. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5):

Use a classe [ScriptIntrinsicBlur](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html) do Android para criar o efeito de *blur*:

Exemplo de uso, adaptado desta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22374201/2556111) do SOen:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Bitmap blurRenderScript(Bitmap smallBitmap, int blurRadius) {

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(smallBitmap.getWidth(), smallBitmap.getHeight(), smallBitmap.getConfig());

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getContext());
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation inAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, smallBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE);
    Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output);
    script.setRadius(blurRadius);
    script.setInput(inAlloc);
    script.forEach(outAlloc);
    outAlloc.copyTo(output);

    rs.destroy();

    MutableBitmap.delete(smallBitmap);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu uso uma biblioteca muito simples pra fazer esses efeitos.

https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

Para usá-la é bem simples:

Adicione a depêndencia:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.3'
}
```

Depois de você estanciar a imagem, você define o Blur, exemplo:

```
Blurry.with(this)
                .radius(10)
                .sampling(8)
                .color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))
                .async()
                .animate(500)
                .onto(sua_imagem);
```

Comment: cara vc postou a mesma lib q eu coloquei em cima -_-

Comment: Não tinha visto sua resposta, estava fazendo a minha de forma correta, já que você só jogou um link ai sem explicação nenhuma. Abraços.

Answer (score -1):

Eu utilizo essa colasse para fazer o blur nas imagens

[Blurry Efect](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

espero que ajude.
no próprio git vem explicando como incluir a lib e como executar o cod, com poucas linhas você faz o blur nas imagens.